# Can you save a online library in the spiffs so you can access it offline

Tags: javascript, iot, esp8266, esp32, spiffs

Hallo my question is quite simple. I have made some IOT projects and U am wondering if you would be able to save e.g. a javascript library in the spiffs on the esp32 or esp8266 and then retrieve it in the browser.

The way you normally do it is like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but I wonder if you can do something like this if it is saved in the spiffs and you made the right code

```
<script src="https://192.168. 0.1/library"></script>
```

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: Web server library has examples of serving files from SPIFFS, so what's the problem here?

Comment: There is no problem i just could not find any videos on youtube or any articles on google that could confirm that you would be able to send JS librarys to a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send save JavaScript libraries or similar in spiffs and then send it to the web page.

If anyone has problems with it here's some help. The way you do it in HTML is to write it like this.

```
<script src="/JQ"></script>
```

If you are working with ESP8266 then the code for the request should look like this

```
server.on("/JQ", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  request->send(SPIFFS, "/JQ.js");
```

Where it finds the saved file in the spiffs and sends it to client.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).